# If you don't map over futures, could this lead to subtle bugs?

Tags: scala

Say I have a code snippet like this that deals with futures:

```
productService.insert(product).map {
   case Right(p) => Right(p)
   case Left(err) =>
       logger.error(s"product insert failed for $p")
       productService.remove(p)   // returns Future[Boolean]
       Left(err)
}
```

So since I am calling the `remove` method, but I am not mapping over the result, this call my return `false`, which means the remove failed, and this will never be logged as an error.

Is it always best practise to map over futures to inspect their return values?

Is there a name for this type of subtle bug?

Comment: You should be using a `flatMap` there.

Comment: I would like to recommend the `-Wvalue-discard`  compiler option. It will issue a warning for code like that because the `Future` returned by the `remove` method is being discarded.

Answer (score 3):

You chain `Future` with `flatMap`. If you really want to keep `Either[Throwable, T]` in your `Future`:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def insert(value: String): Future[Either[Throwable, String]]
def remove(value: String): Future[Boolean]


insert("product").flatMap {
  case Right(p) => 
    Future.successful(Right(p))
  case Left(err) => 
    remove("product")
      .map(isRemoved => if(isRemoved) Left(err) else Left(new RuntimeException("On failure remove didn't work")))
}
```

To answer directly to your question: Yes it could lead to bugs as there is no guarantee `remove` will finish or be successful.